# Angular: animate a nested component on :leave & :enter states

Tags: angular, animation, triggers, children

I would like to animate an element's DOM insertion/removal, which is triggered by a parent higher up in my component tree, as follows:

```html
<component-A>
  <component-B *ngIf="condition">
    <component-C>
      <div @fadeEnterLeave>animated element</div>
    </component-C>
  </component-B>
</component-A>
```

(Note that the components are not "transcluded" (no **Content Projection** using `ng-content`); they're just direct and only children in their parent's respective template (minimal reproduction to better illustrate my problem: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf7kaq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)))

As is, only the `:enter` transition is animated, for the `component-A`'s sub-tree instantly disappears when `condition` is not met, preventing the `:leave` animation to play.

Now, the [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild#usage-notes) states that:

> Each time an animation is triggered in Angular, the parent animation has priority and any child animations are blocked.

So I need to "trickle" the animation down to `component-C` using the `animateChild` function:

```js
trigger("cascade", [
  transition(":enter, :leave", [query("@*", animateChild())])
])
```

`component-B` template:

```html
<component-C @cascade></component-C>
```

Adding this trigger to `component-B` (which applies the trigger to the `component-C` element in its template) yields my expected result: `:enter` **and** `:leave` animations play for `component-C`'s div.

The catch is that, in my case, `component-A` also registered animations for its template's elements to use, and, for some reason, reusing the `@cascade` trigger (this one alone, even; no other animations) skips `component-C`'s div animations: the `@fadeInOut` trigger is called for both states, but the animation is "done" as soon as it starts.

Again, I might not be very clear, but [the demo is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf7kaq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts).
Open the console to see the logs of every trigger "start" and "done" timings and order. Spoiler: the trigger events don't "bubble up/down" in the tree order.

I'm surely missing something silly because it must be such a common occurrence to want to animate an element's :enter/:leave far away from its parent's `[ngFor]` or `[ngIf]` ?

Thank you for your input!